# how to set the bydefault value of dropdownlistfor when button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set bydefault value `good`  in dropdown list when click the btnSave but not able to set

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> Status = new List<SelectListItem>();
    Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Good", Value = "Good" });
    Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Bad", Value = "Bad" });
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Status, new SelectList(Status, "Value", "Text"), "", new { placeholder = "Select Status", @class = "form-control fds" })

 <a id="btnSave" href="#" class="btn btn-bg-light mr-2" >Save</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
               $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                    console.log("insid btnSave click event");
                   
                    //$('#Status').val('0');
                    $('#Status').val(1)
                    //$("#Status option[text='it\'s me']").attr("selected", "selected");

                    console.log("Status:" + $('#Status').val(1));
                    
                });
</script>
```

I am trying to set by default value `good` in dropdownlistfor when click on btnSave

I am trying this but not work

```
 $('#Status').val(1)
```

Comment: Hi , did you tried like this : `$('#Status').val("Good")`  or `$("#Status option[text=Good]").prop("selected", true);`?

Comment: @Swati if i try this ```var setStatus = $("#Status option[text=Good]").prop("selected", true)``` then see print object object console log ```setStatus[object Object]```

Comment: @Swati not able to find solution can you help more

Comment: Show your html code for select-box

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the jquery, there are no any options value="1" instead replace 1 with "Good"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    console.log("insid btnSave click event");

    //$('#Status').val('0');'
    $("#Status").val("Good");
   

});
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a property in `SelectListItem`  named `Selected`, you can set this to `true` for the item you want to be selected by default.

```
@{
List<SelectListItem> Status = new List<SelectListItem>();
Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Good", Value = "Good" ,Selected=true});
Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Bad", Value = "Bad" });

}

@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Status, new SelectList(Status, "Value", "Text"), "", new { placeholder = "Select Status", @class = "form-control fds" })
```

Comment: not work I am trying and trying but not able to get by default value when click on the button

Comment: Have you set `Selected` as my answer?

Comment: can you add your full answer with javascript jquery yes ```Status.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "good", Value = "good", Selected = true});```

Comment: You don't need `js` script any more, this code that I sent set default value. let me edit my answer, meanwhile, remove your js script and check it again